# Is the simplification of this circuit correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electronics

[image]

It doesn't look right to me as the 8 and 4 resistor and the 30 and 17 ohms resistors just disappeared. Can anyone point out the correct way of simplifying the circuit and providing the equivalent resistance? Without their disappearance, I was unable to solve it.

Comment: The purpose of exercises is for you to do them yourself to test and apply your knowledge. If you are unable to solve, go back to studying the theory and then try again or ask your instructor who is familiar with how this exercise is related to the studied theory and would be in the best position to advise on what specifically you are missing. If your exercises are done by others, you get a fake degree.

Comment: I think you've made a calculation error in the first wye-delta transform.

Answer (score 0):

I see an 8 ohm and a 4 ohm resistor in series. Then I see that combination in parallel with a 12 ohm resistor.

If the dotted lines connecting the 47 ohm resistor mean it's not actually connected, then you have a 17 and a 13 ohm resistor in series.

After that, you've got a couple of places you could use the wye-delta transform. But that requires so much algebra that you'd probably be better off just applying mesh or node analysis to the circuit as it is.